# Stream-like processing of files in Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, gzip

I would like to understand how I can add filters/transformations in a stream starting from a source, going to a sink.

As an example, consider reading a CSV file.  That would be

```rb
CSV.foreach(file) { |row| ... }
```

If I want to read from a zipped file, that would become

```rb
stream = Zlib::GzipReader.open('/tmp/foo.csv.gz')
csv = CSV.new(stream)
csv.each { |row| ... }
```

Now, possibly I would like to add transformations on between gunzip and csv.  What is the best way to achieve this goal in Ruby?

Currently I'm doing this:

```rb
gzip = Zlib::GzipReader.open('/tmp/foo.psv.gz') # Pipe Separated Value (fake example).
trans = IOTransform.new(gzip) { |line|  line&.tr('|', ',') } # A simple example.
csv = CSV.new(trans)
csv.each do |row|
  puts row.inspect
end
```

using the following class

```rb
class IOTransform
  def initialize(io, &block)
    @io = io
    @block = block
    @inbuf = +''
  end

  def gets(...)
    if !@io.eof?
      @inbuf << @io.gets(...)
    end
    res = nil
    remainder = nil
    @inbuf&.each_line { |line|
      if line[-1] == "\n"
        res ||= +''
        res << @block.call(line)
      else
        remainder = line
      end
    }
    @inbuf = remainder
    res
  end
end
```

but it feels like I really missed something: I very much doubt that there's no easy way to process streams in Ruby.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can't you just put your block in the `GzipReader.open`?

Comment: This is not composable.  I would like to be able to build the chain dynamically.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/f4agttd8si-chaining-then-in-ruby-26?

Comment: The syntax is nice, but this is strict, not lazy.  I'm looking for something that works on streams, not by passing the full result of the first stage to the second and so forth.  Or maybe it would work, but I don't see how to use it for streams.  Thanks!

Comment: Your `IOTransform` class seams good enough for the job, but you may need to implement more IO methods (not just `gets`) if you want to use it for other things than CSVs

Comment: Yes, I agree.  But I was wondering if I had missed something.  I'm really surprised there's nothing standard for this jobs.  Thanks!